# Chaining APP_INITIALIZER functions in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to ensure that two items of config are loaded before my application starts while using Angular 6 and Typescript.  I would like to retrieve an API endpoint from a config file, and then use that API endpoint to retrieve some permissions.  The permissions then determine what should be shown on the screen, hence why I really want them to be loaded before the application.

I've read several posts about this including [APP_INITALIZER won't delay initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639136/angular4-app-initializer-wont-delay-initialization), [Runtime configuration](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration) and [Nested HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783437/angular2-app-initializer-nested-http-requests)
.  However they all seem to require there to be one config.service.ts that handles all the config loading that is required.  Is it not better practice to have one service to load the API endpoint (and other pieces of config), and another service to access the API?

I have put together a [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/MR1zOJXX3hLph6lJHxcP/) that demonstrates the two separate services to retrieve the information.  The console is logging the various steps.  The current output is:

```
going to load app settings
getting permissions
undefined (This is the api endpoint retrieved from the config file)
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. 
got appsettings
```

I hope you can see that the code is trying to load the endpoint and trying to use it to retrieve the permissions simultaneously.  The endpoint is actually retrieved after the application is loaded.  I would like to have the api endpoint retrieved, THEN the permissions loaded and then the application loads.  So the desired output is:

```
going to load app settings
got appsettings
getting permissions
https://webapi.endpoint/
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

I'm new to Angular, so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572028/angular-2-app-initializer-execution-order-async-issue) but I don't understand the solution. It seems very related if anyone can help me unpick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took inspiration from [hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e) and rearranged the way I called my promises.  I kept my separate services, but called the permission service from the appsettings service.

app-settings.service.ts:

```
loadAppSettings() {

return (): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('loadAppSettings:: inside promise');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('loadAppSettings:: inside setTimeout');
      this.permissionService.loadPermissions().then(x=> resolve());
    }, 5000);

  })
}
```

permissions.service.ts:

```
loadPermissions() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`PermissionsService:: inside promise`);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`PermissionsService:: inside setTimeout`);
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```